# Getting elements from one function in another one

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This functions work fine when they work alone, but when I try toggle between them, I got same elements in both arrays. Some are multiply by numbers of clicks others not.

```js
var playerBtn1 = [];
var playerBtn2 = [];

var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

playerA();

  function playerA() {
    
    for(let i = 0; i <btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            playerBtn1.push(btn[i]);
            playerB();
            
        }); 

        
}

return playerBtn1;
}
    

function playerB() {

    for(let k = 0; k <btn.length; k++) {
        btn[k].addEventListener("click", () => {
              playerBtn2.push(btn[k]);
              playerA();       
    });  
    
    }

    return playerBtn2;
    
}
```

Edit. I've solved my problem, I just got rid of my functions and one of  Event Listener. Put everything together and it works. Below I post my improved cod.

```js
var playerBtn1 = [];
var playerBtn2 = [];
var click = 0;
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    
    for(let i = 0; i <btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            if(click % 2 == 0) {
            btn[i].innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-5x"></i>';
            btn[i].disabled = "true";
            playerBtn1.push(btn[i].id);
            }
            else {
                btn[i].innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-circle fa-4x"></i>';
                btn[i].disabled = "true";
                playerBtn2.push(btn[i].id);
            }
            click++; 
        }); 
       
        
}
```

Comment: `btn` is all buttons on the page. in both functions you're adding event listeners to all buttons on the page. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

You declared it once and every time when you executing this:

```js
playerBtn1.push(btn[i])
```

your passing reference to same html button (I suppose you have couple of them) every time.

You can try to this instead:

```js
playerBtn1.push(btn[i].cloneNode(true))
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Comment: It's a same effect as I have before. After I clicked 4 times get this                                                              
playerBtn1
(8) [button#1, button#2, button#5, button#5, button#4, button#4, button#4, button#4]

Comment: Yes, but it’s not same reference. This is how it supposed to work. What are you trying to achieve?, cause I’m kinda confused.

Comment: I didn't post all my code because it didnt get posted. My goal is to bulid a simple Tic Tac Toe game and I use buttons as board. First function change innerHTML of btn to cross icon, second to circle. I just need this array to store player's clicks and find is someone wins or is a draw

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

```js
var playerBtn1 = [];
var playerBtn2 = [];
var click = 0;
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    
    for(let i = 0; i <btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            if(click % 2 == 0) {
            btn[i].innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times fa-5x"></i>';
            btn[i].disabled = "true";
            playerBtn1.push(btn[i].id);
            }
            else {
                btn[i].innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-circle fa-4x"></i>';
                btn[i].disabled = "true";
                playerBtn2.push(btn[i].id);
            }
            click++; 
        }); 
       
        
}
```